# Bootstrap selectpicker "data-subtext" does not updating the live changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I want to change my `data-subtext` attribute of the `option`s of my `select` element  in runtime. But `data-subtext` does not get updated in selectpicker.
Here's my code:

```
$('.selectpicker').attr("data-subtext","new subtext").selectpicker('refresh');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `.selectpicker` class stands for the `select` element itself not for it's `option`s. Considering it can have more than one `option` you need to state which `option`'s `data-subtext` you wish to change. refer to the following snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myBtn').click(function() {
    $(".selectpicker > option:eq(1)").data("subtext", "Look I'm changed");
    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker('refresh');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

 <select class="selectpicker">
        <option data-subtext="Mustard subtext">Mustard</option>
        <option data-subtext="Ketchup subtext">Ketchup</option>
        <option data-subtext="Relish subtext">Relish</option>
      </select>
      <a class="btn btn-default" id="myBtn">Update second options data-subtext</a>
```